# Incorrect google data structure when there is a special charcater in url

Tags: schema.org, structured-data

I've defined google schema in my web site, and it's working fine when I'm testing the following urls in google structured data test:

```
exmaple.com
```

or

```
exmaple.com?test=12&check=10
```

but when I test urls like bellow that contain special characters like $amp; the schema is totally incorrect and full of error:

```
example.com?text=12&amp;check=10
```

that is weird because page content in both cases is the same the only difference is the url.
here is the link to structured data test:
[the correct one](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.digibaneh.com%2F%3Ftest%3D23%26check%3D12)
[the incorrect one](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.digibaneh.com%3Ftest%3D23%26amp%3Bcheck%3D12)

I couldn't find what the problem was. when I open the pages in the browser everything is fine, however in structured data test tool and in  google search console there is error and problem. this problem is not limited to this certain in any other page when there is special character in the url the same problem happens. any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I can’t reproduce it. Both versions have plenty of warnings for the `Product` items (the first one 2 more per `Product`, as two properties for `Offer` are missing), but I don’t see any issue related to the URL itself. -- Please include a minimal example as code directly in the question which reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For encoding special characters in URLs, you can use **[Percent-encoding, also known as URL encoding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)**. You can also use the free online tool **[URL Decoder / Encoder](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)**.

Thus, the URL that you told us in the poster after encoding will have the following syntax:

```
exmaple.com%3Ftest%3D12%26check%3D10
```